# How to SELECT round up number in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, divide, modulo

I have a salary table with this column

```
EMPLOYEE_NAME    SALARY
------------------------
ANNA             113750
MARRY            124300
BELLA            105100
```

I want to round up the amount of salary with 2000 or 5000 fractions which is nearby. So for this case it will be like

```
EMPLOYEE_NAME    SALARY
------------------------
ANNA             114000
MARRY            125000
BELLA            106000
```

For additional information, I used MS SQL Server. Please help me to do that. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Unlike `ROUND` (which rounds up and down) the `CELING` function (which you want to round up) has no length parameter (as in `ROUND(salary, -3)`). So divide and multiply to get the desired result:

```
select employee_name, ceiling(salary / 1000.0) * 1000.0 as salary
from mytable;
```

- `CEILING` is documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms189818.aspx
- `ROUND` is documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms175003.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CEILING` function.

Like:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME CEILING(SALARY)
```

[Read this for further details](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/ceiling.php)

*Short summary from the above link:*

> In SQL Server (Transact-SQL), the CEILING function returns the smallest integer value that is greater than or equal to a number.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
select EMPLOYEE_NAME, ceiling(salary / 1000.0) * 1000.0 as SALARY from table;
```

Comment: it wil round to the nearest 1000, not up to 2000 or 5000

Answer (score 0):

Divide the salary by the fraction. Use ceiling to round up. Then multiply by the fraction.

```
Declare @salary table (Employee_name nvarchar(50), Salary money)
Declare @fraction money = 5000

insert into @salary
values
('ANNA',             113750),
('MARRY',           124300),
('BELLA',           105100)

update @salary
set Salary = ceiling(salary/@fraction)*@fraction

select * from @salary
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below CEILING method :

```
  DECLARE @fraction MONEY = 1000

   SELECT CEILING(113750/@fraction)*@fraction 
   SELECT CEILING(124300/@fraction)*@fraction
   SELECT CEILING(105100/@fraction)*@fraction
```